# Two function in ^ implementation

Tags: haskell, haskell-prelude

I don't understand one thing about implementation of `^` in `haskell`:

```
(^) :: (Num a, Integral b) => a -> b -> a
x0 ^ y0 | y0 < 0    = errorWithoutStackTrace "Negative exponent"
        | y0 == 0   = 1
        | otherwise = f x0 y0
    where -- f : x0 ^ y0 = x ^ y
          f x y | even y    = f (x * x) (y `quot` 2)
                | y == 1    = x
                | otherwise = g (x * x) (y `quot` 2) x         -- See Note [Half of y - 1]
          -- g : x0 ^ y0 = (x ^ y) * z
          g x y z | even y = g (x * x) (y `quot` 2) z
                  | y == 1 = x * z
                  | otherwise = g (x * x) (y `quot` 2) (x * z) -- See Note [Half of y - 1]
```

Why do we need `f`? isn't `f x y` is just `g x y 1`?

Is it some optimization or I missing something?

If I change code in a following way will it work?

```
(^) :: (Num a, Integral b) => a -> b -> a
x0 ^ y0 | y0 < 0    = errorWithoutStackTrace "Negative exponent"
        | y0 == 0   = 1
        | otherwise = g x0 y0 1
    where
          g x y z | even y = g (x * x) (y `quot` 2) z
                  | y == 1 = x * z
                  | otherwise = g (x * x) (y `quot` 2) (x * z)
```

Comment: You haven't copied out [the whole source](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Real.html#%5E). If you look more closely, you'll notice that there is a note about inlining and specialization – I suspect this is relevant, though you are correct that these definitions are semantically equivalent.

Comment: @AJFarmar I read it several times and still don't understand how it is relevant.

Comment: @DanielWagner it will violate restriction on `*`. Specifically this `@x * fromInteger 1@ = @x@ and @fromInteger 1 * x@ = @x@`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, `f x y` is not just `g x y 1`: `g x 3 1` calls `g (x*x) 1 (x*1)`, but `f x 3` calls `g (x*x) 1 x`. In particular, the last argument is `x*1` in the former but `x` in the latter. It would be surprising to find an instance for which this makes a semantic difference or a noticeable performance difference, but they are at the very least not the exact same thing.

Comment: As I said it will violate `@x * fromInteger 1@ = @x@ and @fromInteger 1 * x@ = @x@`

Comment: @talex Correct. 1. It is possible (though obviously not recommended) to write instances which violate class laws, and 2. those laws are brand new in the newest `base` documentation, and I know of at least one legacy instance which violates them.

Comment: Agree, but I doubt that this code was created the way it is because of this reason. Otherwise `f` should have same `x * 1` for consistency.

Comment: @talex That is exactly my point: the code may have been created this way explicitly so that `f` could avoid multiplying by one -- perhaps for performance reasons in instances where constructing `1` or multiplying by `1` is not cheap. Think of very large matrices, for example.

Comment: It make sense. It will save few multiplication.

Comment: I wrote that exponentiation code, so here’s a comment. The code is convoluted exactly because it avoids multiplying by 1 when it’s not needed.  You want to avoid this for performance reasons.  And also for esthetic reasons; multiplying by 1is ugly.  Here’s an old blog post of mine:  http://augustss.blogspot.com/2008/07/lost-and-found-if-i-write-108-in.html